# UITabBarController Active Tab Masking Color?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

Quick question, when you are implementing a UITabBarController and you are adding image icons to the tabs is there a way to override the blue active masking color, can you specify your own gradient or a custom image for the background grad?

cheers Gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want complete control you’ll have to roll your own `UITabBarController`.  `UITabBar`’s `-drawRect:` could be overridden to provide a custom background but the bar items are pretty much non-customizable.